# mysql_secure_installation executes, but does not change tables

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a problem that after clean latest mysql or mariadb (10.0.34-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) install on clean Ubuntu 16.04 (on separate VMs), mysql_secure_installation runs happily but does not change a thing! Exactly the same result (to be precise no result whatsoever) if I run SQL:

```
sudo mysqladmin -u root password "my_pass"
sudo mysql -u root -p"my_pass" -e "UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('my_pass') WHERE User='root'"
sudo mysql -u root -p"my_pass" -e "DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='root' AND Host NOT IN ('localhost', '127.0.0.1', '::1')"
sudo mysql -u root -p"my_pass" -e "DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User=''"
sudo mysql -u root -p"my_pass" -e "DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE Db='test' OR Db='test\_%'"
sudo mysql -u root -p"my_pass" -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES"
```

No error, it runs smoothly with no output. But it has no impact on user table. like I never run it.

It is a mystery for me. Obviously I'm missing something very basic, but can't see what. I'd appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

It printed those lines out as *suggestions* of what should be done.

It was not so rash as to do them for you; that could cause grief if there is, for example some reason to fix, rather than `DELETE` one of those 'users'.